# angular 2+ test failing in pipeline but feature is working

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, angular-test

I dont know anything about testing and the feature is working completely but failing in pipeline.

Here is my spec.ts file code

```
let component: CustomerDocumentUploaderComponent;

beforeEach(()=>{
    let clientFilter:ClientFilterService = {} as any;
    component = new CustomerDocumentUploaderComponent(clientFilter);        
});

it("Upload button should enabled when description is specified", ()=>{
    component.uploader.addToQueue([new File([], "testFile")]);
    component.uploader.queue.map(f => (f as FileItem).formData.description = "test description");

    expect(component.isUploadDisabled()).toBe(false);
});
```

Here is my component.ts file

```
export class CustomerDocumentUploaderComponent implements OnInit {

@Output()
fileUploaded = new EventEmitter();

uploader: FileUploader;

@ViewChild('fileInput', { static: false })
fileInput: ElementRef;

isUploadDisabled() {
    return this.uploader.queue.some(fi => (fi as any).description == null) || this.uploader.queue.length == 0;
}
}
```

Above is the complete code... I'm using ng2-fileupload directory in this and the description is a custom property that created here. So, upload will be enable only when description property has any value.

This feature is working perfect but test is failing and unfortunately, I dont have any knowledge about angular testing and all.

Here is html code

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" #fileInput type="file" id="file" name="file" accept=".doc, .docx, .png, .jpg, .pdf, .xls, .xlsx, .csv, .ppt, .pptx" 
           ng2FileSelect [uploader]="uploader" multiple [required]="true" />
</div>
<div *ngFor="let fileItem of uploader.queue">
    <hr />
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="description" name="description" [(ngModel)]="fileItem.file.name" [required]="true" disabled="disabled" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="value">Description</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="description" name="description" [(ngModel)]="fileItem.description" [required]="true" />
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>
        <div *ngIf="uploader.isUploading">
            Uploading:
            <div class="progress">
                <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" [ngStyle]="{ 'width': uploader.progress + '%' }"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <label>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="uploader.uploadAll()" [disabled]="isUploadDisabled()">
                <span class="fa fa-upload"></span> Upload
            </button>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Run `npm run test` locally to see how if the failure on the pipeline is the same locally. If it is the same locally, that is good news. You can fix it locally and hopefully it will pass in the pipeline. It is also important that you share in how it fails (what is the error message).

Answer (score 0):

```
it("Upload button should enabled when description is specified", ()=>{
component.uploader.addToQueue([new File([], "testFile.doc")]);
component.uploader.queue.map(f => (f as FileItem).formData.description = "test description");

expect(component.isUploadDisabled()).toBe(false);
```

});

I just required to write the extension and the error finish.